# How to Remove LineDash from CoreGraphics?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm doing some core graphics to draw a custom pdf.
The design i'm working with uses a dashed line in a couple of places.
And after setting up the dashed line i've found it causes drawing code for solid lines to appear as dashed.
Wondering, how do i remove the `setLineDash` from the context so this doesn't happen.

here's the method where the pdf is being rendered and the context is passed into the method for the solid line and the dashed line.

```swift
    func pdfData() -> Data {
        let pdfMetaData = [
            kCGPDFContextCreator: "Dwellify",
            kCGPDFContextAuthor: "dwellify.com",
            kCGPDFContextTitle: "test"
        ]
        let format = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
        format.documentInfo = pdfMetaData as [String: Any]
        let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)
        let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in
            context.beginPage()
            let titleBottom = workOrderOverview(pageRect: pageRect)
            let labourMaterialsBottom = labourAndMaterials(pageRect: pageRect, textTop: titleBottom)
            _ = dwellifyImg(pageRect: pageRect, imageTop: 0)
            
            let context = context.cgContext
            var divBottom = divider(rect: CGRect(x: margin, y: labourMaterialsBottom, width: contentWidth, height: 10),
                                    context: context)
            
            //description & address
            let dABottom = descriptionAddress(start: divBottom, context: context)
            
            divBottom = divider(rect: CGRect(x: margin, y: dABottom.y + 5, width: contentWidth, height: 10),
                                context: context)
            
            //Section Header
            let xyBottom = sectionHeader(title: "General Services",
                                         origin: CGPoint(x: margin, y: divBottom.y + 5),
                                         context: context)
            
            let o = section(lineItem: wo.lines[0].items!.first!, origin: xyBottom, context: context)
            
            let pgNmbrRect = page(number: 1, context: context)
            
            //inject correct origing after finishing lines
            _ = signatureSection(origin: CGPoint(x: margin, y: pgNmbrRect.minY), context: context)
            
            
        }
        
        return data
    }
```

here's the solid line method

```swift
    func divider(rect: CGRect, context: CGContext) -> CGPoint {
        if isDesigning {
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            context.addRect(rect)
            context.fillPath()
        }
        
        context.saveGState()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.gray5.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)
        context.strokePath()
        
        return CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    }
```

Here's the dashed line method

```swift
    func dashedLine(rect: CGRect, context: CGContext) -> CGPoint {
        if isDesigning {
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            context.addRect(rect)
            context.fillPath()
        }
        
        context.saveGState()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black1.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)
        context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [3, 2])
        context.strokePath()
        
        return CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `restoreGState` before you return from your drawing routines. This will isolate any changes made to the graphics context to that call. You already have calls to `saveGState` in your code, but moving it to the start of the method and using `defer` to call the restore minimized the chance of you forgetting to do it.

For example:

```swift
    func dashedLine(rect: CGRect, context: CGContext) -> CGPoint {
        context.saveGState()
        defer { context.restoreGState() }

        if isDesigning {
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            context.addRect(rect)
            context.fillPath()
        }
        
        
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black1.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)
        context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [3, 2])
        context.strokePath()
        
        return CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    }
```